# How to check only "On Time" checkboxes?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I am trying to check only checkboxes where "Flight Status" is "On Time" on this URL

http://loadrunnertips.com/LoadRunner_Correlation_Challenge_Mod.aspx?dd=1&game=Team%20Handball

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Here I screenshoted HTML base.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYN5P.png

This is what I got so far, but it seem not to work.

```
Select Checkbox  name:On Time
Press Keys  xpath://*[@id="head_btnNext3"]  [return]
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the checkbox is not 'On Time',
it is 'head_chk5'

Can be the case that that is dynamically.

try this:

```
Select Checkbox  id:head_chk5
Press Keys  xpath://*[@id="head_btnNext3"]  [return]
```

furthermore, read this and use the conditional execution.

https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/05/robot-framework-tutorial-loops-conditional-execution-and-more/

that should do the trick.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for an answer, but it is after every refresh changing, so I cannot staticly select row. Do you have solution for that?

Comment: I think this is in the direction you should think of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54410228/how-to-write-a-regular-expression-utilizing-the-robot-framework-to-find-replace

Answer (score 0):

So get the ID's of the cases matching....

${match1}=  get regexp matches  ${ExpectedFileAsString}  [A-Z][a-z]+\s\d+,\s\d\d\d\d

then

for i in range bla
Select Checkbox  ${match1}

I don't know exactly but something like that.